# Finding the form of the equation of the curve given some conditions

Tags: limits, functions, curves, upper-lower-bounds, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am having difficulties to find the form of the equation of the curve $y=f(x)$.

$f(x)$ has the all of the following properties:

- it is continuous (and not piecewise),
- always increasing,
- having at most one inflection point, (depends on our requirement, the constants of $f$).
- it has upper bound.

---

For example, the common equation of a sigmoid is invalid,

say the equation is $y=a+\frac{b}{1+e^{cx}}$, now when $c=0$, then the second condition is not valid because we are told that $f$ is always increasing.  Otherwise, it will always have one inflection point, this makes the third condition invalid because if we require no inflection point, we can not fix the constants.

---

Another example of invalid form; $y=A-Be^{Cx}$, because if we require one inflection point, then we can not have it by changing $A,B,C$

---

See the following to illustrate my problem:

[image]

The red curve: No inflection point, and the rate (or the slope) is always decreasing

The purple curve: There is one inflection point, and the rate (the slope) is increasing slowly, but then decreasing rapidly.

The green curve: There is one inflection point, the rate (or the slope) is increasing slowly, then increasing rapidly, and then decreasing slowly.

The blue curve: There is one inflection point, the rate (or the slope) is increasing slowly, then decreasing slowly.

---

The equations of these curves, I believe, have a common form. I tried to guess, but I did not reach to any answer.

I also tried to use more than $3$ constants.

---

Any help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

$\tan^{-1} x$.

It is continuous on $\mathbb R$.

$\dfrac d{dx} \tan^{-1}x = \dfrac1{1+x^2} > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

$\dfrac {d^2}{dx^2} \tan^{-1}x = -\dfrac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}$ which is equal to $0$ only at $x=0$.

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \tan^{-1}x = \dfrac\pi2$ is the upper bound.

Comment: $\tanh (x)$ is also a cool function!

Comment: $\arctan(x)$  does not satisfy the requirements. Sorry if my English is bad and you did not understand my question. Other way of asking: If the given curves (red, purple, green, blue) all have the same form of equation, what could be that form?

Comment: @vb628 kindly read my comment, you may understand what I mean. $\text{arctanh(x)}$ is invalid too. Because of the same reason why sigmoid is invalid.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari I did say $\tanh(x)$ not the inverse. $\tanh(x)$ has derivative $\text{sech}^2 (x)$ which is positive on $\mathbb{R} .$

Comment: Both $\arctan$ and $\tanh$ satisfy ALL your constraints.

Comment: @player3236 having at most one inflection point, (depends on our requirement, the constants of f). Depends on our requirement is must, if we want no inflection point, then? That condition is mentioned in my post.

Comment: You got my point dear?